# Recruiter called for interview followup results, missed call and no callback day later?

Tags: interviewing, recruitment

May be silly but I'm a student who graduates in may and got an interview with a company I've always wanted to work for. Interview went really well and was told to expect a call back this week. I received a call yesterday morning while I was in class and missed it due to my phone being on silent. She left a voicemail to call her back for a interview follow up, I called back immediately which was 30 mins passed the original one and left a voicemail. After receiving no call back the entire day, I tried recalling at 5 pm and no answer still.

She has not called me back and its been almost a day and a half now and I'm really not sure what to do. I don't want to keep calling and bug her but it seems really weird to not call me back? Any advice, do you think they somehow moved on?

Comment: Just call back a few more times until you reach her. You are overthinking this.

Comment: There’s no way any of us could know why she hasn’t called you back. Just be patient. She probably has a lot of other things to deal with besides you.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I properly follow-up with a hiring manager, to check on the status of a position?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/6018/how-do-i-properly-follow-up-with-a-hiring-manager-to-check-on-the-status-of-a-p)

Answer (score 2):

> Any advice, do you think they somehow moved on?

Given that she left a voicemail telling you to call her back to do a interview follow-up I doubt they "moved on", probably just missed your call (like you did) and haven't got time to call you back.

I suggest you keep trying to call them back. This is hardly something that could be perceived as "bugging", as they explicitly told you to call them back, and besides is a relevant matter (and not just calling for some unrelated matter).

You can also try reaching them via email if they provided you with one (most surely they did). You can also try contacting them via their web page given they have one.

If they happen to call you during classes you could try stepping out for a moment to take the call, you can then ask them to call you on a specific time or well take the follow up right there.

Usually follow ups are shorter than a interview by phone or other similar calls, and most probably just calling to schedule the next round of interviews, so I doubt that call will take too long.